# Using COUNT with GROUP BY and FIELD counting rows where value does not exist

Tags: mysql, group-by, count, left-join, union

I spent more time writing my title than I did this post lol. I hope it makes sense.

I'm not sure if this is possible but I have a statement where I need to count the total records with a particular value using `GROUP BY status` and `FIELD(status, 'value1', 'value2', 'value3', 'value4', 'value5')`.

The issue is that in my `FIELD` values (value1, value2...) that value may not exist in any records so I need the count to return 0

```
SELECT COUNT(*),status FROM table WHERE some_field = 12345 GROUP BY status ORDER BY FIELD(status, 'value1', 'value2', 'value3', 'value4', 'value5');
```

returns

```
|COUNT(*)|status|
|3       |value1|
|9       |value2|
|12      |value3|
|34      |value5|
```

As you can see it is counting all the records fine, but the issue is that there is no `value4` in any of the records so it returns nothing. What I need it to do is return

```
|COUNT(*)|status|
|3       |value1|
|9       |value2|
|12      |value3|
|0       |value4|
|34      |value5|
```

I was also messing around with `IFNULL(COUNT(*), 0)` and `IFNULL(status, 0)` but it returns the same results with the missing value. Basically, I need to specify the values I am looking for and return 0 if none exist.

I also tried `HAVING status = 'value1' OR status = 'value2' OR status = 'value3' OR status = 'value4' OR status = 'value5'` but adding this also does not return 0 on the missing row/value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a query that returns 2 columns: the `status` values that you want and the order of each status.
Then join the table to that query with a `LEFT` join and aggregate:

```
SELECT s.status, COUNT(t.status) counter
FROM (
  SELECT 1 id, 'value1' status UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 'value2' UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, 'value3' UNION ALL
  SELECT 4, 'value4' UNION ALL
  SELECT 5, 'value5'
) s LEFT JOIN tablename t
ON t.status = s.status AND t.some_field = 12345
GROUP BY s.id, s.status
ORDER BY s.id;
```

Comment: Where do I put the `WHERE` clause?

Comment: @CesarBielich the ON clause. See my edited code.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks so much

Answer (score 0):

You have to join the complete data list

you can use UNION for all status

```
SELECT
    IFNULL(t1.count_1,0) "count", t2.status
FROM
(SELECT 
    COUNT(*) count_1, status
FROM
    table1 
WHERE
    some_field = 12345
GROUP BY status
ORDER BY FIELD(status,
        'value1',
        'value2',
        'value3',
        'value4',
    'value5')) t1
        RIGHT JOIN (SELECT 
        'value1' as status
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 'value2'
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 'value3'
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 'value4'
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 'value5') st1 on t1.status = st1.status
```